# Help with CSS float on div's

Tags: css, css-float

In this I want the div `#intro` to float below the div `#navtop`.

At the moment it hovers below on the right side.

```
   <style> 

  #wrapper {
   width:850px;
   height:auto;
   margin:auto;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }

  #header {
   height:100px;
   width:850px;
   margin:0;
   margin-top:25px;
   background:url(img/header.png) no-repeat #000 ;
   border:2px #000 solid;
   }

  #navtop {
   width:auto;
   height:45px;
   float:left;
   background:#000;
   padding-right:8px;
   }

  #navtop a {
   width:500px;
   margin:0px;
   margin-left:8px;
   padding-left:4px;
   padding-right:4px;
   color:#FFF;
   padding-bottom:0px;
   text-decoration:none;
   }

  #logo {
   height:40px; 
   width:40px;
   margin-left:4px;
   }

  #navtop a:link {
   background:#666;
   }

  #navtop a:hover {
   color:#999;
   }

  #intro {
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
   float:left;
   background:#666;
   margin-top:70px;
   padding:4px;
   border:2px #000 solid;
   }

  #about {
   width:500px;;
   height:auto;
   float:right;
   background:#666666;
   margin-top:25px;
   padding:5px;
   border:2px #000 solid;
   }

  h2 {
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#FFF;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   }

  body {
   background:#999;
   }

 </style>

  </head>

 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="navtop"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="40" height="40" />
<a href="link.php">Home</a>
<a href="link.php">About</a>
<a href="link.php">tour</a>
<a href="link.php">photos</a>
<a href="link.php">contact</a>
</div>
<div id="intro">
   <img src="img/djpic.jpg" width="300" height="450" alt="pic" /></div>
   <div id="about"> <h2>DJ TECHIE LUNCHBOX</h2> 
  <p>DJ Techie Lunchboxis the current dj who knows what an audience thinks , her upside down skiiny fettish style sjing will
  leave any with a head without for for chips and shandy . chocolate malnurishment bring a        chip bang mismosh to her long term goals
 .</p>
 .
 </div>


 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Remove float:left; from #intro

Comment: You have an extra semicolon after `width:500px;` in `#about`.

Comment: @Sparky - extra semicolons do not cause problems.

Comment: @andi, yes, and I didn't say it did.  Otherwise, I would have down voted it.  Since it's just sloppy code, I made a helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `float: left;` on `#intro`.

Try this:

```
 #intro {
width:auto;
height:auto;
clear:left;
float:left;
background:#666;
margin-top:70px;
padding:4px;
border:2px #000 solid;
 }
 #about {
width:500px;;
height:auto;
float:left;
background:#666666;
margin-top:25px;
padding:5px;
border:2px #000 solid;
```

}

edited to make the `#about` div float next to `#intro` div.

Comment: Thanks , that worked but i want to get the 'about' div floated to the left of it .

Comment: so you want the divs like this
[navtop] then the next line
[intro][about]  
?

Comment: @frank: If you're trying to float that div to the left, why is it set to `float:right`?

Comment: ok the intro looks great but about is on the right but it's below intro.

Comment: if you want about on the left of intro, put about's html before intro's html in your html document

Comment: i tell a lie , it's just silly dreamwaever's preview looks great in the browser . thanks

Comment: @frank:  Please accept this answer if it solved your problem and refrain from telling us lies.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want that floated to the left of whatever the other box (I assume you do), try adding a `clear: left` to the #intro CSS. This will cause the box to break down to below whatever element is causing it to move to the right and start a new line.

```
 #intro {
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 background:#666;
 margin-top:70px;
 padding:4px;
 border:2px #000 solid;
 clear:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use `float:left` on #navtop. It wants to line #navtop and #intro divs beside eachother

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish but i will take a stab at it

you could target your #navtop with a rule

```
#navtop{clear: right;}
```

or simply remove the float: left from the #intro

either one of these will move the #intro under the nav

however if you want the intro to be next to something you will have to use clear:right on navtop